# (Java) How do you generate a random integer between 1 to 4 using SecureRandom

Tags: java

An assignment I'm working on right now needs to generate a random number from 1 to 4 using SecureRandom that will be used for a switch statement. Cases have to start from 1 so I can't just use

```
SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
int a;
a = rand.nextInt(4);
```

right?
I have to use SecureRandom to generate the integer as well.

Answer (score 2):

You're off by one (a very common source of errors). Of note is that `rand.nextInt(n)` will return a value from `0` to `n - 1`. You want

```
int a = 1 + rand.nextInt(4);
```

Also, make sure you reuse that `SecureRandom` instance (don't recreate it in a loop for example).